# What is the difference between Injectivity and Surjectivity of $f(n)=n^2$ and $f(n)=n^2-2$ when $f:\mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathbb {N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know if there is differnece between the functions when $f:\mathbb {N} \rightarrow \mathbb {N}$

1. $f(n)=n^2$
2. $f(n)=n^2-2$
3. $f(n)=n^2+1 \rightarrow f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb {N}$

for (1.) its injective and not surjective ( example : there is no $n$ that $f(n)=5$ ) what about (2.) and the following?

Thanks!

Comment: (2) is not well-defined, since $f(1)$ is not in the codomain.

Comment: if the function is not well-defined so its not injective and not surjective? I dont check it at all?

Comment: More precisely: the formula $f(n)=n^2-2$ does not define a function from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{N}$. So if your definitions of "injective" and "surjective" only apply to functions, then they don't apply here.

Comment: if for number 2 you let n=1, f(n)=-1 which is not an element of N, so this can not even be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function from $X$ (the domain) to $Y$ (the codomain) must map elements of $X$ into $Y$. If there's some element of $X$ that cannot be mapped, or some element of $X$ that maps outside $Y$, then that function is not well-defined; and hence, it's **not** a function.

For example,

1. $\begin{array}{rccc}f: & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{N}\\
    & n & \mapsto & \dfrac{n}{3} \end{array}$ is **not** a function, since $f(1) = \dfrac{1}{3} \notin \mathbb{N}$.
2. $\begin{array}{rccc}f: & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Q}\\
    & n & \mapsto & \dfrac{1}{n} \end{array}$ is **not** a function, since $f(0) = \dfrac{1}{0} (!)$ cannot be defined.
3. $\begin{array}{rccc}f: & \mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0 \} & \to & \mathbb{Q}\\
    & n & \mapsto & \dfrac{1}{n} \end{array}$ is a function from $\mathbb{Z} \backslash \{ 0\}$ (i.e, the set of integers without the element 0) to $\mathbb{Q}$ (the set of rationals).

---

Back to your question, (2) is cllearly **not** a function, since $f(1) = -1 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

---

(3) is **neither** injective, nor **surjective**.

- To disprove injectivity, can you find 2 **different** integers $n_1$, and $n_2$, such that $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$. Hint $(-1)^2 = 1 = 1^2$.
- To disprove surjectivity, can you find an element in the **codomain** $\mathbb{N}$, such that there's no elements in the **domain** $\mathbb{Z}$ that maps to it?

Comment: (1.) and (2.) are from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, I know, since its codomain is $\mathbb{N}$, $-1$ is out of it (for problem (2)).